# how to make CircularFloatingActionMenu like android in c# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

i use materialDesign Mahapps at c# wpf.
and i want make some floating button that open and spread other button when i click it.

i saw CircularFloatingActionMenu animation in android.

i already saw it

https://github.com/MaterialDesignInXAML

but i couldn't get something.

please see this([CircularFloatingActionMenu animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40446977/circularfloatingactionmenu-animation)) and this(https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui/blob/master/art/CircularFloatingActionMenu.gif) and know me how do i make it...

Comment: You've not described what exactly the issue you're facing. Please post some code and describe what you can't get to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll need is to use a `StoryBoard` [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-animate-a-property-by-using-a-storyboard) in WPF to animate several properties of the animated buttons such as Width/Height/Rotation/Opacity and X/Y to appropriate final location. You'll probably need another one to do the reverse.